# Send multiple attachments with wp_mail in PHP

Tags: php, customization, attachments, email

I'm trying to send multiple attachments with `wp_mail()` , after some issues of attachments names (it displayed something like `phprTxfd.pdf` instead of `file_name.pdf`), i succeeded to display the name of the attachment.

But when i'm trying to send multiple attachment, it only display the first attachment in the mail, and not the others.

Here is my code :

```
function my_custom_email_content_type($content_type) {
    return 'text/html';
}

if (!function_exists('wp_handle_upload')) {
    require_once (ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
}

$files = $_FILES['fichier'];

$upload_overrides = array(
    'test_form' => false
);

$attachments = array();

foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {

    if ($files['name'][$key]) {
        $file = array(
            'name' => $files['name'][$key],
            'type' => $files['type'][$key],
            'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key],
            'error' => $files['error'][$key],
            'size' => $files['size'][$key]
        );
        $movefile = wp_handle_upload($file, $upload_overrides);
        $attachments[] = $movefile['file'];
    }

}

add_filter('wp_mail_content_type', 'my_custom_email_content_type');

wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments);
```

I think the issue is coming from tha line `$files = $_FILES['fichier']` just save the first file in the variable.

I tried to put $files as an array, but it doesn't work.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

print_r($files) display this :

```
Array (
    [name] => Array ( [0] => logo1.png [1] => logo2.png )
    [type] => Array ( [0] => image/png [1] => image/png )
    [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => C:\xamp\tmp\phpC62D.tmp [1] => C:\xamp\tmp\phpC62E.tmp )
    [error] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 )
    [size] => Array ( [0] => 4440 [1] => 7830 )
)
```

when i'm trying to insert 2 or several files in my file input multiple.